# php remove results of regex from file content

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the result of my regex from a file.. how should I do this...

```
$pattern = "/<a href=\"(.*?)a>/s";
$html = file_get_contents('content.html');

$check = preg_match_all($pattern,$html,$match);


foreach($match[1] as $result)
{ 
//  what should I put here
}
```

Comment: use `preg_replace ( $pattern , $replacement , $subject` instead of preg_match_all. After that you should save it into your file.

You don't need the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove the result of my regex

Use `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match_all`.

```
$pattern = '~<a href=(.*?)</a>~'; // only match on same line
$html = file_get_contents('content.html');

$check = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

Comment: thanks... I lose my breakline with this regex.. would you know why ?

Comment: That is probably due to `/s` flag in your regex. Try removing that.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify what you mean by `I lose my breakline` first. Is it removing `<p>` or `<br>` tags also?

Comment: see updated code and post your latest code if still `\n` is being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

This regex will remove the `content.html` and replace with `null`.

```
$pattern = "/<a href=\"(.+?)\">/s";
$html = file_get_contents('content.html');
$subject="<a href="content.html">" 
$check = preg_replace($pattern,'',$subject); //preg_replace('pattern','replacement','subject');
```